# OS X firewall popup about growlnotify keeps popping up

Tags: macos, autotest, growl

I have autotest setup with growlnotify using growl_glue (version 1.0.7):

```
require 'growl_glue'
GrowlGlue::Autotest.initialize do |config|
  config.notification :use_network_notifications => true
end
```

growl version is 1.2

each time autotest runs and displays the notification growl popup I also get an OS X firewall popup asking `Do you want the application "growlnotify" to accept incoming network connections?`

I tried answering deny and allow but it still keeps popping up.

the deny/allow choice is properly reflected in System Preferences -> Security -> Firewall -> 'application access list', but it still asks every time.

#### update

I ended up using autotest-growl gem instead of the growl_glue. it fixed the problem, it was probably related to how growl_glue was calling growlnotify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the Remote Desktop application. To fix it I trashed the folder located at /Contents/_CodeSignature inside the application package. I would try that for growl.

Here's the [forum](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=8800878#8800878) post where I found the solution back when I was troubleshooting it.

Comment: hmm. the problem is that its not Growl, but growlnotify which is a command line utility. just a binary, not a full-fledged OSX app. so there is no /Contents/ directory for it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

- Type "which growlnotify" into terminal to find out where growlnotify
  is installed.
- Open System Preferences
- Click on Security padlocked house icon
- Click on Firewall
- Click on padlock and type password if necessary to unlock the
  configuration
- Click on Advanced... button
- Click on plus button.
- When the file picker comes up, type "/" to get a text box, then hit
  backspace.
- Paste in growlnotify's location.
- Click "Go" button
- Click "Add" button
- Click "OK" button

Did it work for you?

Comment: you should have read the update on the question. I no longer have the problem. since then I also upgraded OS to Lion, so again, no problem. have no way to test it.

Comment: I use latest Growl from AppStore, and for me command "which growlnotify" print nothing.